# determining conjugates in the lamplighter group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given two elements of the lamplighter group 
$$ g = (n,(\ldots,l_{-1},l_0,l_1,\ldots)),$$
$$h = (m,(\ldots,k_{-1},k_0,k_1,\ldots))$$
how can one determine if they are conjugates?

I’m not really sure how to approach this problem. I presume that the order of the two elements has to be the same. I can not figure out what the defining relationship between two conjugate elements of the lamplighter group is.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The problem becomes easier if you see the lamplighter group $L$ as the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2[t,t^{-1}])$ defined by $$L=\Big\{A_{k,f}=\pmatrix{t^k & f \cr 0 & 1 }, f\in \mathbb{F}_2[t,t^{-1}],k\in\mathbb{Z}\Big\}.$$ The isomorphism is given in the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group

Easy computations shows that we have $A_{m,h}A_{k,f}A_{m,h}^{-1}=A_{k, t^m f+h(1-t^k)}$.

So $A_{k,f}$ and $A_{\ell,g}$ are conjugate if and only if  $k=\ell$ and there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g-t^mf$ is divisible by $(1-t^k)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[t,t^{-1}]$.